# Node-Webkit sharing data in node via exports

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm experimenting with Node-Webkit lately, if I call sth like that;

```
exports.name = function() {
    console.log('My name is Uğur');
};
```

Node-WebKit renderer throws a error:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"
```

I couldn't understand, Is it caused by node-webkit or node.js itself. Since; 'node test.js'
works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this in the Node's context (not WebKit's context). To do that, specify the script in 'node-main' in the manifest.

Here is an example:

index.js:

```
exports.callback0 = function (win) {
}
```

index.html:

```
<body onload="process.mainModule.exports.callback0(window)">
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "node-main": "index.js",
  "main": "index.html"
}
```

HTH

Comment: thanks but I couldn't understand; we can call sth directly from webkit context like this; "var request = require('request')" , also node-webkit examples do that a lot. Is this special to exports ?